# AngularJS scope in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a way to utilize the angularjs inside jquery? I have the following code:

```
$scope.reloadContainer = 
        function(){
            <div class="thumbnail box gameThumbnail" ng-repeat="image in images" gameId=" {{image.GameID}}|{{image.MachineID}}" gameName="{{image.MachineDescription}}" gameDesc="{{image.LongDescription}}">';
            $scope.images = [$scope.images[0]];
            string += '<div class="game-title">{{image.MachineDescription}}</div>';

            angular.element($("#games-container")).scope().$apply();
            $("#games-container").append(string);

        };
```

After appending the string, it only displays {{image.MachineDescription}} in the front-end. Can anyone help me to figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you probably want to be using jQuery inside an angular directive.

Comment: Yes. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: It looks to be a wrong way to use angularjs... if you can tell us what you are trying to do probably we could help you more...

Comment: The basic problem here is you need to use the $compile service if you want angularjs interpolation to work on a html content

Comment: I tried using $compile but it is logged as undefined

Comment: Did you include `$compile` in your dependencies? `.controller("myCtrl", ["$compile", function($compile) { }])`

Comment: I got the following error Error: error:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'scope' is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angularjs inside jquery but I warn you it is not the best practice, since you can do whatever you want to do with jquery, you should always do it inside a directive/service but you should avoid something like jquery inside a controller which is a poor practice to do.

But if you have no other option (I had a scenario like this, but your case does not look like extreme case), you can always get the scope of the parent controller/directive by catching an element and using scope() function like:

//you can always get the scope of the dom element using:

```
var $scope = angular.element("domElement").scope();
```

//compile service is called

```
var html = $compile('<div>some HTml</div>')($scope); //you need the scope to compile the html
angular.element('#parent').append(html); //appending the html with all the events.
```

But, this solution is when you dont have an option. You should use ng-hide and ng-if to just display when you need(I might be wrong but I think you can use those in your problem). Use the solution only when you get html from some other source which gives static htmls but ask you to perform angular stuff on the html at the frontend side, which is rare.

Comment: Thank you @Kop4Lyf! Finally, got it working. My solution is the same.